# Minimum of a list up to that point in the loop

Tags: python, list, min

I have a list of tuples containing 2 numbers like below. I essentially need to know the current minimum for how far into the list I am, hopefully outputting something like l2.

```
l = [(30, -182), (55, -160), (72, -143), (92, -183)] 
l2 = [(30, -182), (55, -182), (72, -182), (92, -183)]
```

I've tried using enumerate but keep encountering:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

The code I'm using so far:

```
for i,(ss,en) in enumerate(sdat):
    print ss, min(x[1] for x in sdat[:i])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint 1: first iteration when `i==0`. Hint 2: `sdat[:i]` won't include i'th element. Also why won't you evaluate minimum in each iteration based on cached minimum? These calls to `min` are expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're getting a bit confused.

```
for i,(ss,en) in enumerate(sdat):
```

You don't need indexes as long as you can keep history, so there's your first hint.

```
    print ss, min(x[1] for x in sdat[:i])
```

You're *rerunning* `min` (incorrectly) every time; this is a lot of work to compare two numbers.

Just do this manually:

```
sdat = [(30, -182), (55, -160), (72, -143), (92, -183)] 

if sdat:
    ss, en = sdat[0]

for ss, new_en in sdat:
    if new_en < en:
        en = new_en
    print((ss, en))

#>>> (30, -182)
#>>> (55, -182)
#>>> (72, -182)
#>>> (92, -183)
```

---

Also, to prove that I'm supeh functional and stuff, here's what I'd actually do:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def oddmin(a, b):
    return b[0], min(a[1], b[1])

accumulate(l, oddmin)
```

Requires 3.3 and up, so this won't work for Jsg91.